# Simple examples for cases in which gradient descent diverges

Tags: convergence, gradient-descent

I am trying to acquire an intuition and understanding of cases in which [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Description) (GD) diverges.

I have found some questions ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/161715/215801), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/315664/215801), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274336/215801)) in which people tried to minimize a popular cost function using GD, but it diverged.
 However, I am looking for very simple examples aimed directly at understanding the foundations, without all of the "noise" that a solution to a real-world problem comes with.

Let's denote:

- $f(x)$ - a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) to find the minimum of (using GD)
- $m = \text{argmin }f(x)$
- $k$ - step number
- $x(k)$ - the input to $f$ after step $k$
- $d(k) = |x(k)-m|$, i.e. the distance from the minimum (with regard to inputs to $f$)
- $\eta(k)$ - learning rate

The examples I look for:

1. $\eta(k)$ is constant, and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d=\infty$.
2. $\eta(k)$ is constant, and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d\not=\infty,0$, i.e. the GD doesn't converge to infinity, but "stuck in some infinite loop".
3. $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space \eta (k)=0$ and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d=\infty$, i.e. the GD converges to infinity, even though $\eta$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 5):

## Example 1: $\eta(k)$ is constant, and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d=\infty$

Let $f=x^2$.
Then:
$$
\begin{gathered}m=0\\
\nabla f\left(x\right)=2x\\
d\left(k+1\right)=\left|x\left(k+1\right)-m|=|x\left(k\right)-\eta\left(k\right)\nabla f\left(x\left(k\right)\right)-0\right|=\\
\left|x\left(k\right)-\eta\left(k\right)2x\left(k\right)\right|=\left|x\left(k\right)\right|\cdot\left|1-2\eta\left(k\right)\right|=\\
\left|x\left(k\right)-m\right|\cdot\left|1-2\eta\left(k\right)\right|=d\left(k\right)\left|1-2\eta\left(k\right)\right|\\
\downarrow\\
d\left(k+1\right)=d\left(k\right)\left|1-2\eta\left(k\right)\right|
\end{gathered}
$$

Therefore, assuming that $x(0)\not=0$, it holds that $d(k)$ is a geometric progression that converges to $\infty$ for any $\eta>1$.

E.g. for $\eta=1.01$:
[image: Example 1]
(Points get darker as $k$ increases.)

## Example 2: $\eta(k)$ is constant, and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d\not=\infty,0$

Let $f=x^2$.
As shown above, $d\left(k+1\right)=d\left(k\right)\left|1-2\eta\left(k\right)\right|$, so for $\eta=1$, we get $d\left(k+1\right)=d\left(k\right)\left|1-2\right|=d\left(k\right)$, i.e. $d(k)$ is constant, and $x(k)$ is the sequence $x(0), -x(0), x(0), -x(0), ...$

[image: Example 2]

By the way, it is interesting to see that for $\eta=0.5$, the GD converges after a single step for any $x(0)\not=0$.

## Example 3: $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space \eta (k)=0$ and $\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\space d=\infty$

Let:

- $f=x^4$
- $\eta\left(k\right)=\frac{1}{k+1}$.
- $x(0)=1$

Then: $$\begin{gathered}m=0\\
\nabla f\left(x\right)=4x^{3}\\
d\left(k+1\right)=\left|x\left(k+1\right)-m|=|x\left(k\right)-\eta\left(k\right)\nabla f\left(x\left(k\right)\right)\right|=\\
\left|x\left(k\right)-\eta\left(k\right)4\left(x\left(k\right)\right)^{3}\right|=\left|x\left(k\right)\right|\cdot\left|1-4\eta\left(k\right)\left(x\left(k\right)\right)^{2}\right|=\\
d\left(k\right)\cdot\left|1-4\frac{\left(d\left(k\right)\right)^{2}}{k+1}\right|\\
\downarrow\\
d\left(k+1\right)=d\left(k\right)\cdot\left|1-4\frac{\left(d\left(k\right)\right)^{2}}{k+1}\right|
\end{gathered}
$$
Therefore, if $d(k)\ge k+1$ (which also means that $d(k)\ge 1$), then:
$$\begin{gathered}
\frac{\left(d\left(k\right)\right)^{2}}{k+1}\ge1\\
\downarrow\\
\left|1-4\frac{\left(d\left(k\right)\right)^{2}}{k+1}\right|\ge3\\
\downarrow\\
d\left(k+1\right)\ge3d\left(k\right)
\end{gathered}
$$
and also:
$$\begin{gathered}d\left(k+1\right)\ge3d\left(k\right)\ge3\left(k+1\right)\ge k+2\\
\downarrow\\
d\left(k+1\right)\ge k+2
\end{gathered}
$$
We chose $x(0)=1$, so $d\left(0\right)\ge0+1$, and we can prove by induction that $d\left(k+1\right)\ge3d\left(k\right)$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$.
Thus, $d(k)$ is a geometric progression that converges to $\infty$.

[image: Example 3]
($x^4$ is truly a wild function, so the GD explodes so fast that I managed to get a reasonable image for only 6 points, and I had to use $x(0)=0.76945$.)

Here is my code for making the animations, from which the images were taken:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def f1(x):
    return x ** 2

f2 = f1

def f3(x):
    try:
        return x ** 4
    except OverflowError:
        print('x is too large... (The growth of x ** 4 is just crazy)\n'
              'I am afraid you have to just make INTERVAL bigger, and be '
              'satisfied with 3 data points :( ')
        exit()

def f1_grad(x):
    return 2 * x

f2_grad = f1_grad

def f3_grad(x):
    return 4 * x ** 3

func_to_grad_dict = {f1: f1_grad,
                     f2: f2_grad, 
                     f3: f3_grad}
func_to_sane_range_dict = {f1: (-1.8, 1.8, 0.01),
                           f2: (-1.8, 1.8, 0.01), 
                           f3: (-5, 5, 0.01)}
func_to_color_diff_dict = {f1: 0.03,
                           f2: 0.03, 
                           f3: 0.3}


def learning_rate_1(k):
    return 1.01

def learning_rate_2(k):
    return 1

def learning_rate_3(k):
    return 1 / (k + 1)

x0_1 = 1
x0_2 = 1
x0_3 = 0.76945

def plot_func(axe, f):
    xs = np.arange(*func_to_sane_range_dict[f])
    vf = np.vectorize(f)
    ys = vf(xs)
    return axe.plot(xs, ys, color='grey')

def next_color(color, f):
    color[1] -= func_to_color_diff_dict[f]
    color[1] = max(0, color[1])
    return color[:]


###########################################
# script parameters
X0 = x0_1
F = f1
LEARNING_RATE = learning_rate_1
INTERVAL = 1
INTERVAL = 3e1
INTERVAL = 9e2
INTERVAL = 3e2
###########################################


k = 0
x = X0
f = F
f_grad = func_to_grad_dict[f]
cur_color = [0, 1, 1]

fig, (k_and_x, x_and_y) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9,5))
k_and_x.set_xlabel('k')
k_and_x.set_ylabel('x', rotation=0)
x_and_y.set_xlabel('x')
x_and_y.set_ylabel('y', rotation=0)
plot_func(x_and_y, f)
k_and_x.plot(k, x, '.', color=cur_color[:])
x_and_y.plot(x, f(x), '.', color=cur_color[:])
plt.tight_layout()

def update(frame):
    global k, x

    gradient = f_grad(x)
    x -= LEARNING_RATE(k) * gradient
    k += 1

    color = next_color(cur_color, f)

    print(f'k: {k}\n'
          f'x: {x}\n')

    k_x_marker, = k_and_x.plot(k, x, '.', color=color)
    x_y_marker, = x_and_y.plot(x, f(x), '.', color=color)

    return k_x_marker, x_y_marker

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, blit=False, repeat=False, interval=INTERVAL)
plt.show()
```